# pastebinit doesn't work correctly

Tags: pastebin

The `pastebinit` in my system(`Fedora 21 32-bit`) doesn't work as expected, such as:

`echo asdasdas | pastebinit`

The output is:

`http://fpaste.org/`

nothing else, it should be something like `http://fpaste.org/spdvsd` right?

I didn't use pastebinit very much, I remembered that a long time ago, the same thing happened to to me once, and I didn't figure it out at that time either. But after I re-installed my whole system because of some other reason, pastebinit worked again.

So can anyone here tell me the reason???

Answer (score 0):

The API had some changes since, try updating the pastebinit package to v1.5 or build it from the source : [pastebinit-1.5.tar.gz](https://launchpad.net/pastebinit/trunk/1.5/+download/pastebinit-1.5.tar.gz)